# Nodejs Performance measurement: What is the magnitude used in the percentiles?

Tags: node.js, performance, event-loop

According to Node js documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_perf_hooks_monitoreventloopdelay_options), I am trying to measure the event loop lag of my application. Following this code in the documentation:

```
const { monitorEventLoopDelay } = require('perf_hooks');
const h = monitorEventLoopDelay({ resolution: 20 });
h.enable();
// ....
console.log(h.percentiles);
```

Output is:

```
Map {
0 => 1202176,
50 => 2260992,
75 => 2318336,
87.5 => 2334720,
93.75 => 2342912,
96.875 => 2347008,
98.4375 => 2351104,
99.21875 => 2377728,
99.609375 => 2670592,
99.8046875 => 3000320,
99.90234375 => 6770688,
99.951171875 => 6942720,
99.9755859375 => 27770880,
100 => 27770880
}
```

**What is the magnitude used in the percentiles?** Can I get it in milliseconds?

Comment: So. we're done here then?

Comment: Yes, i should have checked the documentation better before asking.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@RafaelPáezBastida](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11550995/rafael-p%c3%a1ez-bastida)'s question post.

> Found the answer in [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_perf_hooks_monitoreventloopdelay_options):
>
> *The delays will be reported in nanoseconds.*